# Построение SQL на основе XML файла

Tags: javascript, sql, xml, typescript

Всем привет!
У меня возник вопрос по поводу XML и SQL.
У меня стоит задача:построить базу данных и у меня есть XML файл с различными данными(до этого с XML не сильно часто работал).Вопрос:

1.Возможно ли это вообще сделать?(не вручную :D ибо файл большой)
2.Если да,то как это возможно?
3.Если нет,то что?)

Стоит упомянуть что мой XML файл супер большой.Где-то гигов 2 :).

Comment: Если данные чётко структурированы, то парсишь, потом формируешь SQL запросы `INSERT INTO`

Comment: Да,чётко структурированы.А каким образом парсить их?И во что именно парсить?

Comment: все возможно. копайте xslt

Comment: благодарю)Буду копать

Comment: Ваша база данных (СУБД) и ее версия?

Comment: Postgres. 14.4 вроде